# notifydataSetChanged working but only showing 1 result in listview Android

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, notifydatasetchanged

Hi i have an issue where only 1 result is being shown when i call a notifydataSetChanged function. I have read in this forum that the Array list needs to be cleared, then the data needs to be added for the notifydataSetChanged to work properly. I have followed that, but the problem is when the new data arrives it clears all the other data and only shows the latest item from the list. I know its a clear() issue, but i cant work out how to fix it. Any suggestions would be gratefully appreciated.

My Adapter :

```
public MessageAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<ArrayList<ReadMessage>> list) {
    mContext = context;
    mList = list;
    mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int pos) {
    return mList.get(pos);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    CompleteListViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = li.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
        viewHolder = new CompleteListViewHolder(v);
        v.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (CompleteListViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }
    viewHolder.messageText.setText(mList.get(position).get(position).getMessage());
    viewHolder.fromText.setText(mList.get(position).get(position).getSender());
    return v;
}
```

}

```
class CompleteListViewHolder {
    public TextView messageText;
    public TextView fromText;

public CompleteListViewHolder(View base) {
    messageText = (TextView) base.findViewById(R.id.message);
    fromText = (TextView) base.findViewById(R.id.user);
}
```

The following method is where i am adding items to the list :

```
  private void addItemsToList() {
       sentMessages.clear();
         sentMessages.add(localstoragehandler.getUserComments(MessageService.USERNAME, friendUsername()));
      messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

The addItemsToList() is called when new data arrives from the web service.

Thanks

Comment: because it is not the same references .... adapter using (simple version) copy of it

Comment: Your notifyDataSetChanges is very strange, you need just to change data in the list if it needs to and call it, no refreshAdapter is needed

Comment: I only added refreshAdapter as i read on a post earlier that it may fix it

Comment: I have updated the code removing the refreshAdapter function.

Comment: Use list.invalidateview() instead notifydatasetchanged

Comment: list.invalidateviews() doesnt work either :-(

Answer (score 0):

What's probably happening is that your list `sentMessages` is what you used to initialize your `MessageAdapter`, correct? By calling `mList.clear()` since it points to the same object as `sentMessages`, you are clearing everything from both lists (which is really just the exact same list). What I would do is change your `MessageAdapter` constructor to the following:

```
public MessageAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<ArrayList<ReadMessage>> list) {
    mContext = context;
    mList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<ReadMessage>>();
    mList.addAll(list);
    mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
```

Comment: Thank for the answer, i changed the consructor, but now im not getting no items in the array list. any sugestions please.

Comment: @n4zg Yeah, I took a second look and realized that might happen. Can I ask why you need to clear the ArrayList? I know you said you've read it on this forum, but I'm really not sure you need to. What happens if you keep your original code, but get rid of the `clear()` call and the `addAll()` call? So you just call `sentMessages.add(...)` and then `notifyDataSetChanged()`?

Comment: il give it a go now , previously i have tried something similar with my constructor and it didnt update the arraylist, il try with the your constructor now

Comment: removing clear()  with new constructor, didnt work, so i reverted to my constructor, i get all the results in the listview but when new data arrives the listview is not updated until i refresh the whole fragement